# Definir columnas y filas según orientación del dispositivo

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Estoy tratando de realizar una pequeña aplicación en la que necesito mostrar los datos organizados en filas y columnas dependiendo de la orientación del dispositivo. Es decir, si está en horizontal sería una sola fila con dos columnas al 50% de ancho de la pantalla cada una y si está en vertical, una sola columna con dos filas al 50% del alto. 
Estoy intentando hacerlo con un grid, pero no sé si sería mejor de otro modo... ¿alguna idea?

Comment: Es una buena idea, puedes usar por ejemplo el grid de bootstrap, define grillas para 4 tamaños de dispositivos Extra small devices Phones (<768px), Small devices Tablets (≥768px), Medium devices Desktops (≥992px), Large devices Desktops (≥1200px).

Comment: Perdona @jorge londoño, soy nuevo en xamarin, pero o me equivoco o ¿lo que me comentas es para una aplicación web? si no es así, no tenía ni idea de que podía usar bootstrap en xamarin.forms

Comment: Si, tiene soporte, mira:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/

Comment: Ah ok, gracias le echo un vistazo!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Creas un StackLayout con nombre "stackLayoutPrincipal" en el archivo .xalm

y en el archivo .cs sobreescribes el métodfo OnSizeAllocated tal que así

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        if (width != this.width || height != this.height)
        {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            if (width > height)
            {
                stackLayoutPrincipal.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
            }
            else
            {
                stackLayoutPrincipal.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
            }
        }
    }
```